# How to add a scroll bar in PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova

I have to add a scroll bar in PhoneGap. Please check my code below.

```
public class MyActivity extends DroidGap {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

        // Display vertical scrollbar and hide horizontal scrollBar
        super.appView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        super.appView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        // set scrollbar style
        super.appView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    }
}
```

I get an error in this statement:

```
super.appView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
```

Comment: u need to use iscroll for having scroll to phonegap application here is an example check [This](http://pastie.org/4404244)

Answer (score 2):

Mobile WebKit (iOS and Android, etc) does not provide a native way to scroll content inside a fixed width/height element, but many libraries can help you with that issue.

I use the [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) to scroll the content in my PhoneGap app. It's a very lightweight framework, only focuses on the scroll problem of mobile WebKit browser or WebViews, and it works perfect.

Here is a simple [example](http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/simple/) .

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you haven't added this line

```
import android.view.View;
```

before

```
public class MyActivity extends DroidGap {
```